# Use List to populate labels C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-ce

I'm creating a device application in VS 2005.

I created a List called "info" and want to populate labels on my form with the values from the List. This is my code:

```
public List<String> info = new List<String>();
int i = 0;


private void populateinfo()
    {
        conn.Open();
        string query;
        query = "select distinct dp.current_location_code,dci.dest_location_code,dps.order_no,dps.company_id_no,dps.no_of_full_cartons,dps.dc_grv_id_no,s.sku_code from dc_pallet_stock dps, dc_pallet dp,sku s , purch_order_carton_sku pocs , dc_crane_instruc dci where dp.pallet_id_no = dps.pallet_id_no and dps.order_no = pocs.order_no and dps.company_id_no = pocs.company_id_no and dps.carton_code = pocs.carton_code and s.sku_id_no = pocs.sku_id_no and s.company_id_no = dps.company_id_no and dp.pallet_id_no = '" + palletId + "' and dci.pallet_id_no(+) = dps.pallet_id_no";
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
        OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            this.info.Add(dr["order_no"].ToString());
        }
        dr.Close();
        conn.Close();
    }

private void frmInfo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        populateinfo();
        lbl3.Text = this.info[++i];
    {
```

Im getting error at `lbl3.Text = this.info[++i];`

> Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index.

This is how I'm testing it at the moment, but at the end I want all the columns in my query to be shown in separate labels, how would I do this. Or is there a better way of doing it? Gridview is no option.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you even populating the `info` array? You don't in the code you show us. This is why you are getting the out of range exception.

Comment: @hetelek That was only a typo. I have corrected it. Still getting the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

palletId in my select query was incorrect. Please see constructor:

```
public List<String> info = new List<String>();
int i = 0;

public frmInfo(string palletId)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.palletId = palletId;
    }

private void populateinfo()
{
    conn.Open();
    string query;
    query = "select distinct dp.current_location_code,dci.dest_location_code,dps.order_no,dps.company_id_no,dps.no_of_full_cartons,dps.dc_grv_id_no,s.sku_code from dc_pallet_stock dps, dc_pallet dp,sku s , purch_order_carton_sku pocs , dc_crane_instruc dci where dp.pallet_id_no = dps.pallet_id_no and dps.order_no = pocs.order_no and dps.company_id_no = pocs.company_id_no and dps.carton_code = pocs.carton_code and s.sku_id_no = pocs.sku_id_no and s.company_id_no = dps.company_id_no and dp.pallet_id_no = '" + palletId + "' and dci.pallet_id_no(+) = dps.pallet_id_no";
    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query, conn);
    OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr.Read())
    {
        this.info.Add(dr["order_no"].ToString());
    }
    dr.Close();
    conn.Close();
}

private void frmInfo_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    populateinfo();
    lbl3.Text = this.info[++i];
{
```

Answer (score 1):

What I probably would do would to create either an Array of your labels or a List of your labels iterate through it. Here is an example dynamically creating your labels and adding them to your form.

```
public List<String> info = new List<String>();
public List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     populateinfo();
     for (int i = 0; i < info.Count; i++)
     {
         labels.Add ( new Label(){Name="lbl"+i+1, Text=info[i], 
                                  Font = new Font("Arial",8),
                                  ForeColor= Color.Blue});

     }
     placelabels();
}

private void placelabels()
{
    int topvalue = 0;
    foreach (Label item in labels)
    {
        item.Left = 0;
        item.Top = topvalue;
        this.Controls.Add(item);
        topvalue += 20;

    }
}
```

And a method adding your existing labels to a List

```
public List<String> info = new List<String>();
public List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    labels.Add(label1);
    labels.Add(label2);
    labels.Add(label3);
    labels.Add(label4);
    labels.Add(label5);
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     populateinfo();
     if (labels.Count > info.Count)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < info.Count; i++)
         {
             labels[i].Text = info[i];
         }
     }
     else
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < labels.Count; i++)
         {
             labels[i].Text = info[i];
         }
     }

}
```

Comment: Been looking for this for a while, works like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try to use like this.

```
...
    while (dr.Read())
     {
            lbl3.Text += dr["order_no"].ToString() + "\n";
     }
...
```